# Xcode debugger not identifying problem

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access

I am working on an app in Xcode and I have found out that that is some unknown reason which makes my app crash. However, when I run my app on a device using Xcode's debugger, this error does not occur. The error only happens when I run it in instruments, or just on the phone by itself. I was wondering if anyone knows how I could get the debugger to show me where the problem is because I believe that I am most likely over releasing something.